# mouseover animation is not working right on the mouse fast moves

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build something like the sliding images on the header of this site 
http://www.metalmonde.co.uk/

Here is my live page
http://mehrdadkhoshbakht.com/test/index.html

It works fine-ish when I slide the mouse over each `div` and wait a little
but when I run the mouse over all of them quickly it doesn't work correctly, especially the little popup sub divs at the bottom (for picture title).

My code is below. Divs with the `pics` class are those sliding divs and the `sub` class divs are the little title divs at the bottom.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="pics" id="pic1"><div class="sub">cccc</div></div>
    <div class="pics" id="pic2"><div class="sub">mmm</div></div>
    <div class="pics" id="pic3"><div class="sub">mmmm</div></div>
    <div class="pics" id="pic4"><div class="sub">mmm</div></div>
    <br  class="clearfloat"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header .pics {
    width: 86px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
.header .pics .sub  {
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    top: 250px;
    display: none;
}
.header #pic1 {
    background-color: #0CF;
    width: 400px;
}
.header #pic2 {
    background-color: #0C9;
}
.header #pic3 {
    background-color: #C30;
}
.header #pic4 {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.pics').mouseover(function() {
            /* firs resetting all the sub divs at the bottom to default (in case of Previous event) */
            $('.sub').hide();
            $('.sub').css('top','250px' );

            /*  ///////////////////////////// */

            $('.pics').not(this).animate({width:"86"},500 )
            $(this).animate({width:"400"},500 , function(){;
                var sub_div = $(this).find('.sub' );
                sub_div.show();
                sub_div.animate({top:"-=20"},500);
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: There is an extra `;` on this line: `$(this).animate({width:"400"},500 , function(){;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $('.pics').mouseover(function(){
       $('.sub').hide().css('top', '250px');
       $('.pics').not(this).stop(true).animate({width: 86}, 500);
       $(this).stop(true).animate({width: 400}, 500, function() {
            var sub_div = $(this).find('.sub');
            sub_div.show().animate({top: "-=20px"}, 500);
       });
   });
});
```